# 2-D arrays - Slicing and Indexing

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Consider the following code:

```
arr = np.random.randn(3,3)
print(arr)

>>> array([[-0.46734444,  0.56493252, -0.26263957],
           [-0.08779416, -2.29891065, -0.49095811],
           [-1.75290304,  0.21304592, -0.91466817]])
```

I tried to get the top right 2 X 2 square matrix using these 2 methods:

```
print(arr[:2,1:])    
print(arr[:2][1:]) 

>>> [[ 0.56493252 -0.26263957]
     [-2.29891065 -0.49095811]]

>>> [[-0.08779416 -2.29891065 -0.49095811]]
```

However, the 2nd method gave wrong answer. I do not understand the behaviour of 2nd method. Please explain!!

Comment: `arr[:2,:][:,1:]` is the correct way to obtain the same answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. row index and column index start at 0
2. when you slice by a list, the start index is inclusive and end index is exclusive. For instance, `arr[:2]` will give you a list of `row[0]` and `row[1]`

`print(arr[:2,1:])`

1. You're taking taking `row[0]` and `row[1]` and taking all columns starting from the 1st column from the 2 rows.

`print(arr[:2][1:])`

1. You're taking `row[0]` and `row[1]` via `arr[:2]`
2. You're again taking just the 1st row from the previous result.

Hope this helps.